# Count the number of unique occurences in a MySQL column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a column status:

```
1 row with status_1

3 rows with status_2

2 rows with status_3

7 rows with status_4
```

I want to write a query that gets all available statuses, groups them, and get the number of occurences then fetch the data as follows:

```
Status 1: 1

Status 2: 3

Status 3: 2

Status 4: 7
```

NB: The statuses are not already known. And we are not talking about DISTINCT or GROUP BY to count the number of unique values (it must be a separate number for each status)

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT status, count(*) count
FROM your_table
GROUP BY status;
```

See [MySQL Group BY](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx) tutorial

Answer (score 1):

According to data you seem want `GROUP BY` with `COUNT()` only

```
select status, count(*) as noofoccurences 
from table t
group by status;
```